# Existing Manifest (build error)

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to add splashscreen on my application. I clean build the program but I selected the wrong file. Now I edited the VM Option and clean build again the second time, now I'm getting this error:

> C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjectInOOP\nbproject\build-impl.xml:975:
>   Existing manifest
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjectInOOP\build\null209371772
>   is invalid BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)

It's pointing to this part:

```
<target depends="init,-do-jar-create-manifest,-do-jar-copy-manifest" if="do.archive+main.class.available" name="-do-jar-set-mainclass"> <manifest file="${tmp.manifest.file}" mode="update"> <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/> </manifest> </target>
```

But when I remove this part on manifest, it can clean build again:

> SplashScreen-Image: splashPack/flash.gif

Anyone? Or is there other alternative? I'm using netbeans.

Comment: are you making a jar?

Comment: Yes. and I'm trying to clean build it but I'm still having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not found a solution yet, just remove all the new lines in manifest.mf

I was also facing this error on the same SplashScreen line, just remove empty new lines.

**Example:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
SplashSceen-Image: splashPack/flash.gif;**

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Hashir: 
I too had same problem after adding SplashScreen-Image: splash/splash.png in the "Manifest" file. But your solution worked for me. I deleted the blank line and then clean and build worked perfectly.

[image]

The above image shown worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Copy & move your line code up the first line (Example like this)

```
SplashScreen-Image: your_package/Splash.xxx 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

NOTE : `Splash.XXX` (xxx must be your file format ".GIF # .gif")